# Picture similarity - Firebase ML Vision or are there other packages?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, similarity

I would like to build a widget in Flutter, that compares the similarity of two pictures a user has shot.

For example

[image: Brandenburger Gate 1]
[image: Brandenburger Gate 2]

I tested this service: https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/image-similarity

And I start playing around with Image labeling in the Google Vision Package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision

I'm still not sure if these are the best ways to do this, is there a different approach?

Thanks
Joerg

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a specific Google Cloud Platform API for that.
You could try playing around with [Vision API's ProductSearch](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/) although it is not meant for your use case and I am not sure that it would well fit it.

What you will need is [image embeddings](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/overview-extracting-and-serving-feature-embeddings-for-machine-learning#image_embeddings).
You can achieve it with a custom image classification model without the softmax function so instead of giving you a label probability, the model will output a feature vector representation of the input image. This feature vector can be used for similarity-matching tasks because it is simply an array of numbers.